# Message Driver Beans Message

Tags: java, ejb, jms

Good Afternoon in my timezone

I am beginning with EJBs , and i have a little question:

snippet of code :

```
public class OrderBilling  implements MessageListener{

   public void onMessage(Message message){
          try{
              ObjectMessage om = (ObjectMessage)message;
              Order order = om.getObject();
```

How the JVM where the MessageBean is running knows how to load the Order class?
RMI is able to download classes from one JVM to another, but because in JMS the MessageBean does not communicate directly with the client but communicates with the JMS server how this process is possible ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: For this to work the Order class should be available to the ClassLoader at the server as well. The data (which is what you are actually exchanging) is serialized inside the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add all the pertinent JARs on both servers: The one sending the message and the one receiving it.

If both are deployed on a Java EE app server like JBOSS, I'd expect to see a JAR file with the shared .class instances in the WEB-INF/lib for both WAR files.

Your classes are no different from a 3rd party JAR: every class loader that needs them should have access.